# What is wrong with this accept header? And what are the rules?

Tags: .net, http, http-accept-header

I have an `Accept` header like this:

`application/myapp+json;version=2.0`

however when I try and use it the constructor for `System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue` rejects it as invalid. Nancy doesn't seem to mind it.

It seems it doesn't like the semi colon. What is the 'right way' to specify a specific version is desired in the header and what are the rules I should follow to generate 'valid' Accept headers?

Comment: You could try adding the header without validation. Also why not just use a `MediaTypeHeaderValue`

Comment: yeah we can work around it, but I want to know what the rules are.

Comment: Tested with something like `var added = client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Accept", "application/myapp+json;version=2.0");` and worked fine. The media type was parsed and the version was added as a parameter of the header.  As for the rules that is way too broad to answer here.

Comment: `MediaTypeHeaderValue` has the same issue, and yes we can add without validation, and maybe the *full* rules is too much for here (but link maybe...), but what is wrong with the header we are using? There should be something obvious should there not?

Comment: I see nothing wrong with your media type at a glance based on my experience with using them